# `RequestPermissionAsync` is not returning and not working as expected. Ask Permission wait for it and GetLocation when permission is allowed problem

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I am new in Xamarin.Forms. I want to ask for the location permission to the user, then  if user allows it, get his location. The problem is `RequestPermissionAsyn` and `GetLastKnownLocationAsync`, both are async operations. Hence I want to wait till user grants permission and then call the `GetLastKnownLocationAsync`. I am using this plugin for Permision [Plugin.Permissions v3.0.0.12](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/)

Here is the code I am using

```
async void AskPermission(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var response = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            var userResponse = response[Permission.Location];
            Debug.WriteLine($"Permission {Permission.Location} {permissionStatus}");
        }
        else
            Debug.WriteLine($"Permission is finally {Permission.Location} {permissionStatus}");
    });

    // Call the GetLocation if user allowed the permission.
}

async void GetLocation()
{
    Location location;
    location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
    Location.Text = location.Latitude.ToString();
}
```

I can successfully prompt the user for allowing permission, but `GetLocation()` is not executing. That means even if I write `Debug.WriteLine("");` whether permission granted?, I am not getting anything in the output Window. Any Help would be much appreciated. Basically I want to run both the asynchronous operations one after the other. I do not understand whether the problem is with asynchronous operations or whether it needs to run from UI Thread.

Comment: Any reason for using `Task.Run`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, Not any specific reason. Can you give me at least the working code. I cannot call any statement after RequestPermissionsAsync(). Even Debug.WriteLine() does not print any output after it. Please help.

Comment: I would start by removing the `Task.Run`. Just run all that code directly in your `AskPermission` event.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, I have done that. Still I cannot display any output after RequestPermissionsAsync(). When user deny permission twice, app crashes with exception TaskCancelledException: 'A task was cancelled'.

Comment: Does the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50338025/1202807) help? (specifically, making sure you override the handler for the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` event)

Comment: @GabrielLuci, I have overriden the `OnRequestPermissionsResult` in my MainActivity of the Android Project.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin Hi ,do you mean even write `GetLocation` in `Debug.WriteLine` there , it does not work? I suggest that not writing it outside of `Task.Run` to have a try .Because `Task.Run` is a asynchronous method ,sometimes the permission not allowed completely , however already invoke the `GetLoaction()` .

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin By the way, do you  have a try with [this method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/geolocation?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android#using-geolocation) .When get location , after permission be allowed , the location will be continued to invoke.

Comment: @GabrielLuci, I think there might be really a problem about `RequestPermissionsAsync` not returning. Hence I have solved it using other method, have a look below or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58939243/8304176

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there might be a problem with `RequestPermissionsAsync` not returning. Hence I have made this modification in my code. Now I ask the user permission using same plugin, and check if the the permission is enabled in other thread. This operation is performed every 1 second until the app gets required permission. When permission is allowed for the app to access location, dispose the timer, hence it will not check for the permissions again.

Also there is another bug in this used plugin inside the project. ([Plugin.Permissions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions/) v3.0.0.12). When we ask for permission 2 times, and both the times if user denies the permission, then Exception was thrown. Hence I caught in inside `try-catch`

This is the working code, someone stuck here might find it useful:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => AskPermission());
    CheckPermissionStatusRepeatedly();
    ...
}

async void AskPermission()
{
    var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Permission Request", "This app needs to access device location. Please allow access for location.", "Ok");
        try
        {
            await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Location.Text = "Error: " + ex;
        }                
    }
}

void CheckPermissionStatusRepeatedly()
{
    Timer timer = null;
    timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(async delegate
    {
        var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            Debug.WriteLine("Still permission is not Granted");
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Now permision is Granted, Hence calling GetLocation()");
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => GetLocation());                    
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }), "test", 1000, 1000);
}

async void GetLocation()
{
    Location location;
    location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
    Location.Text = "Lat: " + location.Latitude + " Long: " + location.Longitude;
}
```

Comment: Wow I spent way to much time figuring out the location permission issue in Xamarin. Thanks for saving some time, really helpful.