# Cannot display output in Output Window Xamarin Forms after async operation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have a code where I request for Location permission and I want to display output whether user has denied or granted the permission. I am not getting any output whether user has granted or denied the permission. I have specified permissions in Manifest as well.

Here is my code:

```
void AskPermissionNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var permissionStatus = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
        if (permissionStatus != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            var response = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Location);
            var userResponse = response[Permission.Location];

            Debug.WriteLine($"Permission {Permission.Location} {userResponse}");   // I cannot display output here
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"2 Permission {Permission.Location} {permissionStatus}");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you [post this again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58919592/1202807)?

Comment: @GabrielLuci, this is different problem, here I am not getting any output after using await. On the previous question I was not able to get location after await. Basically this is generalized problem I am facing.

Comment: When I search Google for ["RequestPermissionsAsync"](https://www.google.com/search?q=RequestPermissionsAsync) I see lots of complaints about it not returning at all. So that's probably the root of your problem. Have you tried debugging and stepping through your code to see if `RequestPermissionsAsync` actually returns?

Comment: Yeah, I think there is a problem with `RequestPermissionsAsync`, for answer refer to my previous question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58939243/8304176.

Comment: @JunedKhanMomin, please post your comment to answer and mark it after three days, it will help others who have similar issue

Answer (score 0):

Your first `await` might throw an `Exception` that stays silent because you're not awaiting the result of `Task.Run` so the exception is not re-thrown.

If you write:

```cs
async Task AskPermissionNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            /* ... */
        });
    }
    except (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Print(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

or

```cs
void AskPermissionNew(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var permissionStatus = await /* ... */
        }
        except (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Print(e.ToString());
        }
    });
}
```

You will probably see the printout of the `Exception` you're currently silently ignoring.

Comment: I am still not getting any output as an exception. I have tried to catch an exception inside try catch. But no exception was thrown.

Comment: So I agree with Gabriel Luci about the fact that your first `await` never returns for some reason.